# Eliminate timestamps within a range from array

Tags: php, arrays, timestamp

This is my array of timestamps. I would like to eliminate values within 30 seconds of each other, only keeping the value if there is not another value within 30 sec. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Array
(
[99999] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1356399000
        [1] => 1356398971
        [2] => 1356399005
        [3] => 1356413406
    )

[99997] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1356399002
        [1] => 1356399007
        [2] => 1356398871
        [3] => 1356398876
    )

[99996] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1356399003
        [1] => 1356399004
        [2] => 1356399008
    )

[99995] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1356399009
    )

)
```

My expected output:

```
Array
(
[99999] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1356399000
        [1] => 1356398971
        [2] => 1356413406 
    )

[99997] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1356399002
        [1] => 1356398871
    )

[99996] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1356399003
    )

[99995] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1356399009
    )

)
```

Any solutions/advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is not an array of timestamps. Do you want timestamps in different sub-arrays to be in range of other timestamps?

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: What have you tried, and can you add an example of the expected result to your question?

Comment: @baba I have added expected output to my original question.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Yes. Each sub-array contains timestamps from a particular user, I would like to eliminate those within 30sec of each other. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeM it does not make sense why 1356413406 was removed from the list .... its not 30 close to any of the values in 99999

Comment: can you explain your self ?

Comment: Yes, I was too quick on the delete button. I have edited. Sorry.

Comment: @Baba also 1356398971 is within 30 of 1356399000 yet appears in the output :-?

Comment: Am not sure you know what you want  .. the property is to first sort the timestamp .. if you do that you would notice that all our output has some issues ..

Comment: @Crisp its obvious he does not know what he wants

Comment: See answer for what i think your output should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is wrong ..  because `1356398971 + 30 = 1356399001` which is grater than `1356399000` if i understand you clearly this i what it should look like

```
$data = array(
  99999 => array(
    0 => 1356399000,
    1 => 1356398971,
    2 => 1356399005,
    3 => 1356413406,
  ),
  99997 => array(
    0 => 1356399002,
    1 => 1356399007,
    2 => 1356398871,
    3 => 1356398876,
  ),
  99996 => array(
    0 => 1356399003,
    1 => 1356399004,
    2 => 1356399008,
  ),
  99995 => array(
    0 => 1356399009,
  ),
);

echo "<pre>";



$data = array_map(function ($values) {
    rsort($values);
    $ci = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($values));
    $values = array();
    foreach ( $ci as $ts ) {
        if ($ci->hasNext()) {
            abs($ci->current() - $ci->getInnerIterator()->current()) > 30 and $values[] = $ts;
        } else {
            $values[] = $ts;
        }
    }
    sort($values);
    return $values;
}, $data);

print_r($data);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [99999] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1356398971
            [1] => 1356413406
        )

    [99997] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1356398871
            [1] => 1356399002
        )

    [99996] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1356399003
        )

    [99995] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1356399009
        )

)
```